# Can someone help me to compare 4 symbolic equations analytically in Python?

Tags: analytic-functions, analyticity, python, symbolic-computation

I have 4 different profit functions and I would like to compare them analytically and find under which conditions what is that ranks of profit functions. For example, I expect an outcome as follows: if xxx is met then profit1>profit3>profit2>profit4

Below you can find the 4 profit functions.
Thanks in advance!

Profit 1:
$π_T^*$=$\frac{(2-δ)^2}{(12-δ ) } $

Profit2:

$π_T^*=\frac{-(F(δ- 2)^2 (5(δ^2- 4b^2 δ + 4b^2 )+ Fδ - 8F))}{(b^2 δ^2- 4b^2 δ + 4b^2+ 8Fδ - 12F+7)^2} $

Profit3

$π_T^*=\frac{-(α^2- 2F + 2Fδ)^2}{5(- α^2+ 4F)(α^2+6F + 2Fδ) }$

Profit 4

$π_T^*=\frac{-(- b^2+ Fα^2- 5Fδ + 4F)}{4(b^2- 3F + 5Fδ) } $